# Trying to add object onto text file

Tags: python, arrays, file, object, procedure

I am trying to upload a bunch of objects onto a text file in an organized manner but I keep on getting an error. I am not sure about objects and how to arrange them so they appear in the text document.

```
class Customer: 
    def __init__(self, name, date, address, hkid, acc):
        self.name = name
        self.date = date
        self.address = address
        self.hkid = hkid
        self.acc = acc

customer1 = Customer ("Sarah Parker","1/1/2000","Hong Kong, Tai Koo,Tai Koo Shing Block 22,Floor 10, Flat 1", "X1343434","2222")
customer2 = Customer ("Joe Momo","7/11/2002","Hong Kong, Tai Koo, Tai Koo Shing, Block 22, Floor 10, Flat 5", "C2327934","1234")
customer3 = Customer ("Brent Gamez","7/20/2002","Hong Kong, Tung Chung, Yun Tung, Block 33, Floor 10, Flat 9", "C1357434","2234")
customer4 = Customer ("Jose Gamez","7/20/2002","Hong Kong, Tung Chung, Yun Tung, Block 33, Floor 10, Flat 9", "C1357434","2234")
customer5 =Customer ("Viraj Ghuman","7/20/2002","Hong Kong, Heng Fa Chuen, 100 Shing Tai Road, Block 22, Floor 20, Flat 1", "C6969689","100000")
allCustom = [customer1, customer2, customer3, customer4, customer5]

def UpdateFile ():
    global allCustom
    OutFile = open("CustomInfo.txt","w")
    for i in range (len(allCustom)):
        for c in range (i):
            OutFile.write(allCustom[i["\n","Name:",c.name,"\n"]])
            OutFile.write(allCustom[i["Birth Date:",c.date,"\n"]])
            OutFile.write(allCustom[i["Address:",c.address,"\n"]])
            OutFile.write(allCustom[i["HKID:",c.hkid,"\n"]])
            OutFile.write(allCustom[i["Account value:", c.acc,"\n"]])
    OutFile.close()
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: `c` is a list index, not a customer. What do you expect `c.name` to be?

Comment: `i` is also an index. What do you expect `i[...]` to be?

Comment: Why do you have two loops? I suspect you meant the second loop to be `c = allCustom[i]`. But you should just use a single `for c in allCustom:` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` and `c` are integer list indexes. You can't use `c.name` because it's not a `Customer` object. And you can't index `i[...]` because it's not a container.

You don't need nested loops, just one loop over all the customers. Your loop iterates `i` from `0` to `4`. On the first iteration it iterates 0 times, on the second iteration it processes `c == 0`, on the third iteration it processes `c == 0` and `c == 1`, and so on.

Then you can use a formatting operator to put the attributes into the strings that you're writing to the file (I've used f-strings below, but you can also use the `%` operator or the `.format()` method).

```
def updateFile():
    global allCustom;
    with open("CustomInfo.txt", "w") as OutFile:
        for c in allCustom:
            OutFile.write(f"\nName:{c.name}\n")
            OutFile.write(f"Birth Date:{c.date}\n")
            OutFile.write(f"Address:{c.address}\n")
            OutFile.write(f"HKID:{c.hkid}\n")
            OutFile.write(f"Account value:{c.acc}\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two loops to get each object info. Maybe this is what you are looking for.

```
def UpdateFile():
    global allCustom
    Outfile = open("CustomInfo.txt", "w")
    
    for i in allCustom:
        Outfile.write(f'\nName: {i.name}\n')
        ...

    Outfile.close()
```

Comment: I don't think `write()` takes multiple arguments, but I'm having trouble finding the documentation that says so.